# Deleting multiple rows from database by checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I want to delete multiple rows from database by checkboxes i have working script for "Check All" but when i want delete one or two , nothing happend.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $("form input[id='check_all']").click(function() { // triggred check

        var inputs = $("form input[type='checkbox']"); // get the checkbox

        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { // count input tag in the form
            var type = inputs[i].getAttribute("type"); //  get the type attribute
                if(type == "checkbox") {
                    if(this.checked) {
                        inputs[i].checked = true; // checked
                    } else {
                        inputs[i].checked = false; // unchecked
                     }
                }
        }
    });

    $("form input[id='submit']").click(function() {  // triggred submit

        var count_checked = $("[name='data[]']:checked").length; // count the checked
        if(count_checked == 0) {
            alert("Please select a comment(s) to delete.");
            return false;
        }
        if(count_checked == 1) {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these comment?");
        } else {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these comments?");
          }
    });
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.submit').click(function(){
            var checkValues = $('input[name=data[]]:checked').map(function()
            {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'resources/ajax/ajax_delete_comment.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: { data: checkValues },
                success:function(data){

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<form method="post" id="form">
Check All <input type="checkbox" id="check_all" value="">

Here im displaying record from database and <input name=\"data[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"data\" value=" . $row['id'] . ">

<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Delete" id="submit">
</form>
```

**DELETING SCRIPT**

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $id_array = $_POST['data']; // return array
    $id_count = count($_POST['data']); // count array

    for($i=0; $i < $id_count; $i++) {
        $id = $id_array[$i];
        $sql = $db->query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        if ($sql)
            {
                echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Failed to delete the comment.";
            }
    }}
```

So its work for check all, but when im checking one or two objects, nothing happend, maybe someone could help?

Comment: If you look in your console. do you see the post request going out in the instances where it "doesn't work"? (in other words -- what doesn't work? The PHP or the JavaScript?) It looks like it would work, and if you say it works with many then it should work with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**
Since you are using jquery there is better way :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var is_activate = true; // we will track which input button was clicked :)

  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#form input#check_all").change(function() {
      var inputs  = $("#form input[type='checkbox']");
      if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        inputs.prop( "checked", true );
        // inputs.attr( "checked", true ); // if its not working
      }
      else {
        inputs.removeAttr( "checked" );
      }
    });

    // Track clicked button
    $("#form input[type=submit]").on("click",function(e) {
      is_activate = ( $(this).hasClass("activate_btn") ) ? true : false;
    });

    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var string  = ( is_activate ) ? 'activate' : 'delete';
      var data    = $(this).serialize();
      var checked = $(this).find("input[name='data[]']:checked").length;
      if ( checked == 0 ) {
        alert( "Please select a comment(s) to "+string+"." );
        return false;
      }
      var text  = "Are you sure you want to "+string+" these comment"+( ( checked == 1 ) ? "?" : "s?" );
      if ( confirm( text ) ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'resources/ajax/'+( ( is_activate ) ? 'ajax_activate_comment.php' : 'ajax_delete_comment.php' ),
          type: 'post',
          data: data,
          success: function( data ) {

          }
        });
      }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="form">
  <label>Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check_all" value="">

  <label>Here im displaying record from database and</label>
  <input name="data[]" type="checkbox" id="data1" value="1">
  <input name="data[]" type="checkbox" id="data2" value="2">

  <!-- Activate Button -->
  <input class="activate_btn" type="submit" name="activate" value="Activate" id="submit">
  <!-- Delete Button -->
  <input class="delete_btn" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**
A single query is enough :)

```
<?php
  if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
    $id_array = $_POST['data'];
    if ( !empty( $id_array ) ) {
      $id_array = implode( ",", $_POST['data'] ); // dont forget to sanitize
      $sql = $db->query( "DELETE FROM comments WHERE `id` IN (".$id_array.")" );
    }
  }
?>
```

And remember, its not good that doing this all in client side.
You can do `POST` request to a single file, since your each `input` button has a unique name.
So in your `PHP` code, you can find which button was clicked like this.

```
<?php
  if ( isset( $_POST["activate"] ) ) {
    $sql  = $db->query( "UPDATE comments SET status = '1' WHERE `id` IN (".$id_array.")" );
  }
  else {
    $sql  = $db->query( "DELETE FROM comments WHERE `id` IN (".$id_array.")" );
  }
?>
```

look how simple :) Isn't it?

Comment: wow, you are fast man, it works :). It possible to add, another submit, like activate comment and join it together with this delete script with url to ajax_update_comment.php?

Comment: I mean adding another input submit to the same form, with the same checkboxes, but when i click "Activate" it should post data to ajax_activate_comment.php.

Avtivate button should be separate from ajax delete script, but i dont know if this is possible, or i must do another javascript.


New button: 

    <input name="submit" class="activate" type="submit" value="Activate" id="submit">

Update:

$sql = $db->query( "UPDATE comments SET status = '1' WHERE `id` IN (".$id_array.")" );

Comment: I did it with single file , thank you very much for help and advices! :)

Comment: arghhh, one more question, im using: window.location.reload(); right now to refresh and delete div's, but i want to do it without refreshing i tried with: $(".aComment"+data).fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();}); aComment is my div block for comments. But this code is fadeing out all (even not deleted) comments, i think i should get comment id's from checkboxes, but how?

Comment: something like `$("input[name='data[]']:checked").parents("div.aComment:first").remove();`