# How do I delete multiple MySQL entries via check boxes?

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, sql-delete

In my application I display the database contents in a table. For each row displayed, I add a check box to the end of the row:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]"></td>';
```

When the user has checked off however many boxes they wish to delete the entries for, they click this delete button (front end is zurb foundation framework):

```
<a href="#" class="button radius expand" id="deleteUrl" name="deleteUrl" onClick="deleteUrl('deleteUrl');return false;">Delete URL</a>
```

When this button is pressed the deleteUrl ajax function is triggered:

```
function deleteUrl(str)
    {
    document.getElementById("content01").innerHTML="";
    if (str=="")
    {
    document.getElementById("content01").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("content01").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","deleteUrl.php?deleteUrl="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("content02").innerHTML = 'Your URL was successfully deleted!<br/><br/>';
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = urlRefresh;
    return;
    }
```

The ajax function directs the process to my deleteUrl.php file:

```
<!--Include Database connections info-->
<?php include('config.php'); ?>

<?php

    $deleteUrl = $_GET ['$deleteUrl'];

    if(isset($_GET['delete']))  {
        if(is_array($_GET['url']))  {
            foreach($_GET['url'] as $id)    {
                $query = "DELETE FROM contact WHERE url=". $url;
                mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());    
            }
        }  
    }

mysql_close();

?>
```

So far the process runs through, without error. However, the entries that are checked are not deleted during the process.

QUESTION: What do I need to do to make the delete process work using check boxes?

EDITED CODE:

```
function runDelete(str, id)

xmlhttp.open("GET","deleteUrl.php?deleteUrl="+str+"&ticked="+id,true);

<a href="#" class="button radius expand" id="deleteUrl" name="deleteUrl" onClick="runDelete('deleteUrl', id);return false;">Delete URL</a>

echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
```

Comment: You should see what is posted first. I would use Mozilla FF with fireBug to see requests and responses. As i see your code it doesnt send the array for deletion. You just send to your PHP 'Delete url'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this,

1 Step - Include jquery url in head tag

2 Step  - include this code after jquery url,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){

        $("#deleteUrl").click(function(){
            $('#content02').html('');
                var tickedItems = $('input:checkbox[name="ticked[]"]:checked')
                   .map(function() { return $(this).val() })
                   .get()
                   .join(",");

                   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "deleteUrl.php",   
                        data: "ids=" + tickedItems,                                        
                        success: function(msg) {

                             $('#content02').html('Your URL was successfully deleted!');

                          }             

                    });

                    return false;
        });
    });

    </script>
```

3 Step - Replace this code in deleteUrl.php,

```
   <!--Include Database connections info-->
    <?php include('config.php'); ?>

    <?php

        $deleteUrl = $_GET ['$deleteUrl'];

        if(isset($_POST['ids']))  {

           $idsArray = @explode(',', $_POST['ids']);               
                foreach($idsArray as $id)    {
                    $query = "DELETE FROM contact WHERE url='".$id."' ";
                    mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());    
                }

        }

    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

4 Step - assign id/property row value into checkbox

```
      <?php 
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="'.$row['id'].'" ></td>';            
      ?>
```

5 Step  - Add this button for delete action

```
<button class="button radius expand" id="deleteUrl" name="deleteUrl" >Delete URL</button>
```

Comment: I tried this method and unfortunately ended with the same result. There were no errors in the browser console, but the data was not deleted.

Comment: Hi Chinnu R, A friend and I looked over this code this afternoon and after making a couple of small changes we got the delete function working with check boxes. Thanks for your assistants!

Answer (score 1):

Corey, it's just suggestion not the exact answer of your query. you should try to make few correction in your code like the steps below.

very first you need to assign the value to checkbox like

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="'.$id.'"></td>';// $id it would different in your case
```

than pass the checkbox values through function call

```
onClick="deleteUrl('deleteUrl',checkboxvalue);
```

and modify function accordingly

```
function deleteUrl(str,checkboxvalue)
```

than pass the checkbox value to delete url

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","deleteUrl.php?deleteUrl="+str+"&ticked="+checkboxvalue,true);
```

than modify delete page to delete the records as per your checkboxvalue not the url and make sure that you are passing correct value from ajax and getting correct value on delete page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can see where I was going wrong with my code. I am still a bit confused in regards to "checkboxvalue". I think this mean the value of my check box that is assigned per row of data (in my case it would be my primary key, . $row['url'] .). However i'm not sure what syntax to use to implement this.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I suggest you to use id instead of url because it may possible url can have special characters and they did not match to db value properly.

Comment: Hi, im sorry to be a pain, but im still having trouble. The process is running without errors with the edited code (see above in the original post for my current code, with your suggestions) but nothing is being deleted. I edited the DB table, there is now and ID which is primary key. Again, sorry to be a pain!

Comment: Corey, I will suggest you to go through with this http://davidwalsh.name/animated-ajax-jquery and add jquery in your code because your code still missing lot of things.

Also look into this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324498/deleting-multiple-rows-from-database-by-checkboxes